# Highlight js applies classes but not styles

Tags: javascript, highlight.js, markdown-it

It seems like `highlight.js` applies classes to my content, but not styles. I'm using `React`, `TypeScript` and `markdown-it`.

Here are my changes to package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "highlight.js": "^9.12.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/highlight.js": "^9.12.3",
```

Here is my markdown file:

```
lua
for i = 1, iterations do
    product.writeln("Starting iteration " .. tostring(i))
    product.writeln("Will run for " .. tostring(duration) .. " msec")

    project:start()
    product.msleep(onoffdelay)

    project:enable_main_power(true)

    product.msleep(duration)

    project:enable_main_power(false)
    product.msleep(onoffdelay)
    project:stop()

    product.writeln("Delaying for " .. tostring(delay) .. " msec...")

    product.msleep(delay)
end
```

Here is what I think is the relevant part of the React component that renders the markdown in html. I'm not very good at Typescript so I set the type of the parameters to string for now. I don't know where to find the type definition for lang.

```
    .then(data => {
        const text = data as string;
        const converted = text.replace(/!\[([^[\]]+)\]\(([^()]+)\)/g, `![$1](${resourceFolder}$2)`);
        const hljs = require('highlight.js'); // https://highlightjs.org/
        const md = require('markdown-it')({
            html: true,
            /* tslint:disable */
            highlight: function (str: any, lang: any) {
                if (lang && hljs.getLanguage(lang)) {
                  try {
                    return hljs.highlight(lang, str).value;
                  } catch (__) {}
                }

                return ''; // use external default escaping
              }
            /* tslint:enable */
        });
        const content = md.render(converted);
        this.setState({
            html: content
        });
    });
```

Here is the rendered html:

```
<pre><code class="language-lua"><span class="hljs-keyword">for</span> i = <span class="hljs-number">1</span>, iterations <span class="hljs-keyword">do</span>
    product.writeln(<span class="hljs-string">"Starting iteration "</span> .. <span class="hljs-built_in">tostring</span>(i))
    product.writeln(<span class="hljs-string">"Will run for "</span> .. <span class="hljs-built_in">tostring</span>(duration) .. <span class="hljs-string">" msec"</span>)

    project:start()
    product.msleep(onoffdelay)

    project:enable_main_power(<span class="hljs-literal">true</span>)

    product.msleep(duration)

    project:enable_main_power(<span class="hljs-literal">false</span>)
    product.msleep(onoffdelay)
    project:stop()

    product.writeln(<span class="hljs-string">"Delaying for "</span> .. <span class="hljs-built_in">tostring</span>(delay) .. <span class="hljs-string">" msec..."</span>)

    product.msleep(delay)
<span class="hljs-keyword">end</span>
</code></pre>
```

The rendered html looks completely plain with no syntax highlighting.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but have you included one of the hightlightjs CSS files?

Comment: @Sirko Not a stupid question at all. I had not. Thanks! Adding a line like import 'highlight.js/styles/darcula.css'; fixed the issue.

Comment: It's a bit much that their docs and their main page don't mention this when importing. Quite the opposite, they say that 'all that's needed' is the import and the function call. Thanks @Sirko